# Let $x$ and $y$ are linearly interdependent and that $x+y+z = 0$. Show that $\theta(x,y) + \theta(y,z) + \theta(z,x) = 2\pi$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, angle, orientation

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 202 Q.11.a, it is asked that

> Let $x,y,z$ be three vectors of a plane such that $x$ and $y$ are
>   linearly interdependent and that $x+y+z = 0$.
>
> a-) Prove that the ordered pairs $x,y; y,z; z,x$ represent the same
>   orientation. Then show that $$\theta(x,y) + \theta(y,z) + \theta(z,x)
>  = 2\pi$$ where the angles refer to the above orientation.

I can see that they represent the same orientation but couldn't show the followed result. I was hoping you can help me on that point.

Comment: How does your text define $\theta(x,y)$? as the lesser of the two (positive) angles determined by vectors $x,y$ each based at the same point?

Comment: @coffeemath $\phi(x,y)$ is defined as the vector between the vector $x$ and $y$, and not necessarily positive.

Comment: @coffeemath I have put a link to the of the book to the question.

Comment: Don't you mean the *angle* between $x$ and $y$? [not the vector] since we get a sum $2 \pi$? Also should there be a "mod $2 \pi$ somewhere?

Comment: @coffeemath the theta is defined originally as $cos (\theta) = \frac{(x,y)}{|x||y|}$, where $|.|$ denotes the norm, and $(.,.)$ denotes the inner product.

Comment: Is it not obvious? Draw it!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Well, it wouldn't prove the result for general since in the question, we are talking about vectors in 2 dimensional real vector space, whereas the geometry that I'm going to use by drawing is just the euclidian geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\theta(y,z)$, $Y=\theta(z,x)$, $Z=\theta(x,y)$.

$$\cos Z=\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|\cdot|y|}$$
$$\cos X=\frac{-x\cdot y-|y|^2 }{|y|\cdot|x+y|}$$
$$\cos Y=\frac{-x\cdot y-|x|^2 }{|x|\cdot|x+y|}$$

We'll need also $\sin X$ and $\sin Y$:
$$\sin X=\sqrt{1-\frac{(x\cdot y)^2+2x\cdot y|y|^2+|y|^4}{|y|^2|x+y|^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{|x|^2|y|^2-(x\cdot y)^2}}{|y|\cdot|x+y|}$$

Similarly,
$$\sin Y=\frac{\sqrt{|x|^2|y|^2-(x\cdot y)^2}}{|x|\cdot|x+y|}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}\cos(2\pi-X-Y)&=\cos(X+Y)=\cos X\cos Y-\sin X\sin Y\\
&=\frac{|x|^2|y|^2+x\cdot y(|x|^2+|y|^2)+(x\cdot y)^2}{|x|\cdot|y|\cdot|x+y|^2}-\frac{|x|^2|y|^2-(x\cdot y)^2}{|x|\cdot|y|\cdot|x+y|^2}\\
&=\frac{x\cdot y|x+y|^2}{|x|\cdot|y|\cdot|x+y|^2}\\
&=\cos Z\end{align}$$